# How to return just the matched objects in array by using a projection in Spring Data MongoDB query?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following document sample in collection:

```
{
  filename : "file";
   filename_exlucde : "exclude";
   product : Array
       0: object{
          x : "11",
          y :  "11",
          z :  "13"
          }
        1: object{
             x : "11",
             y : "12",
             z : "13"
         }
         2 : object{
             x : "12",
             y : "13",
             z : "14"
         }
}
```

I am using the following code to create the query

```
private Query createQuery(){
   Query query = new Query();
   query.fields().include("filename");
   Criteria xcriteria = Criteria.where("x").is("11");
    query.fields().elemMatch("product", xcriteria).include("product.x");
    query.fields().elemMatch("product", xcriteria).include("product.y");
    return query;
}

public List<Data> getData(){
        Query query = createQuery();
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Data.class)
       
    }
```

The problem is that just one element from the array is being retrieved as opposed to two and all fields in the embedded object in array are being included.

expected output

```
{
    filename : "file"
    product : Array
    0: object{
          x : "11",
          y :  "11"
          }
        1: object{
             x : "11",
             y : "12"
         }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @varman updated

Comment: You need to use an aggregation''s `$filter` operator on the array field.